# Did I ruin someone's chances at Jannah? Is that possible?

Tags: jannah, christianity

I did something horrible. About a year ago I was talking about Islam, and a Christian girl showed great interest in the religion. I judged her inside, and thought that this was just a phase and she wasn't serious about it, so I played up how hard and demanding the religion is. I know it was horrible, it was probably one of the worst things I've ever done.

It gets worse. She asked how she could read the Quran and I didn't give her the app she could've used! Needless to say she gave up on the whole thing. Feeling horrendously guilty, I talked to her, apologized, and said that Islam is worth it in the end.

She accepted my apology, but never further studied it sense. Could I have taken away her chance of entering Jannah? Should I talk to her again, or should I let it be with the apology? I'm just so scared that I took away her salvation, and in my eyes that is worse than death.

What should I do?

Comment: This looks more like a call for advice than a practical and answerable question. I would strongly recommend you check our help centre page on [ask] as well as [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to better understand the sorts of questions we encourage here.